# SPRING: Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference

Tags: java, spring, hikaricp, spring-bean

I'm trying to implement hikari but I have this error:

```
/META-INF/datasource.beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

My config:

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="abc_connection_pool" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.informix.jdbcx.IfxDataSource"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="100" />     
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="500" />
    <property name="validationTimeout" value="300" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="30000" />
    <property name="transactionIsolation" value="1" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
        <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
        <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
```

Environment

```
HikariCP version: HikariCP-java6 2.3.13
JDK version     : 1.6
Database        : Informix
Driver version  : Ibm.informix.jdbc 3.00.JC3
```

I change the previous pool that was running by Hikari and I get that error

Comment: From what you've put up it looks like you don't have any dependencies from the config to anything else, so I'm not sure how that could happen.  Maybe debug into spring and see if you can figure out what it sees as a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

The parent tag **beans** was configured **default-autowire = "byName"**
I detele it and solved the problem.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="abc_connection_pool" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.informix.jdbcx.IfxDataSource"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="100" />     
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="500" />
    <property name="validationTimeout" value="300" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="30000" />
    <property name="transactionIsolation" value="1" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
        <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
        <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: What did you removed? Can you please highlight them?